# MySQL Comparison in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, comparison

I have two tables (products and span_products) with many columns each but each has one called part_no,
The should have the same part numbers in both tables but in a different order,

whats the easiest way to show which rows aren't in the span_products table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `left join`

```
select p.*
from products p
left join span_products s on s.part_no = p.part_no
where s.part_no is null
```

See [this explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

Or use a NOT EXISTS:

```
select *
from products p
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from span_products s where s.part_no = p.part_no)
```

I.e. select all products that aren't found in span_products.